What does "buck" mean here?
What does buck mean in the following quote from Axios.com on Twitter? Which sense of buck in online Merriam Webster dictionary applies here?

What troubles Trump's advisers most: He knew that with precision and preparation, Harris would bait him on things like crowd size, and buck discussion about her power today and liberalism in the past.
But he blew it badly ... repeatedly ... predictably.


I suppose it's up to users to look it up, is it? Could you please include at least a link?

Even though this question mentions a dictionary, remember that the whole point is not just to impose dictionary-lookup on you as an empty exercise. The point is that if the dictionary didn't solve things for you, then there's another problem to solve, whatever misunderstanding lies in the way. So for questions about meaning, 1) look it up, 2) tell what you found, and 3) explain how it failed to solve your problem. Close-voting with the "look it up" reason even though this question mentions a dictionary.

We take M+W's part 2, sense 1a definition for buck:

transitive verb: oppose, resist
bucking the system


... Harris would bait him ... and buck discussion about her power today and liberalism in the past.

means Harris would use topics like crowd size to (distract Trump and hence) impede any attempted discussions about her power today and liberalism in the past.
buck

A horse that has not been "saddle-trained" will "buck" (leap and kick out with its legs) in an attempt to throw off anyone who attempts to saddle it and ride it.  By analogy, someone who "bucks" a rule, requirement, or obligation of some kind, or any attempt to control them, is attempting to avoid being "saddled" with that obligation and controlled by it in some manner.
The Axios sentence  is somewhat elliptical, and it can get away with it because "buck" is a common expression (some might say overused). The meaning  is that Harris would not meekly let herself be steered like a saddle-broken horse but would take action ("buck") to avoid having her own record thrust upon her by Trump in an attempt to control the direction she takes in the debate.
